# Read specific lines from .txt file in Visual C#

Tags: file, lines

What I am trying to do is create a small application where users can register and then log into the application. I'm using visual C# (visual studio 2010).

Since I don't really know anything about databases and stuff, I can't use SQL. So what I do is to create a .txt file where I keep all the usernames and passwords etc.

I can successfully create the account and then log in, but when the user logs in I want the next form to contain his data. (like his username,full name etc -- the ones he filled in the register form).

does anyone know how to get the specific data?

the .txt file is something like:
username1
password1
address1
telephone1
date_of_birth1
...
username2
password2
address2
telephone2
date_of_birth2
....
username3
password3
address3
telephone3
date_of_birth3
...

and let's say i want to get the data from the 3rd user to show up on my form.

Comment: You probably want to use something like RavenDb (or my v. simple db https://github.com/mcintyre321/PieDb)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I do not recommend this method to store your user's data at all.

But if this is the only way for you, you can try saving the file as a .CSV, splitting your values and then reading them in an array using linq.

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt").Select(a => a.Split(';'));
var csv = from line in lines
          select new User
            {
                username = data[0],
                password = data[1],
                address = data[2], 
                telephone = data[3],
                dateOfBirth = data[4]
            };
```

Comment: how do I create a .CSV file?

Comment: Manually, you can put your values in Excel and then export it to a .csv file, or with C# you can check out this code: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/415732/Reading-and-Writing-CSV-Files-in-Csharp

Comment: great thanks, but one more thing Ι want it to get the data from a specific user, so how do i search in the .CSV file?

Comment: You could check which line contains the User you want and just subtract the info from that specific line.

Comment: so each line of the .CSV file would contain the data of a user?

Comment: Yes that would be the case, you just separate every property of a User object in 1 row of the CSV, separated with a character (mostly ";")

Comment: something like username1 password1 addresss1 telephone1 dateofBIrth1;

Comment: how can i put the username,password etc into a textbox each?

Comment: If you use this way, you are creating User objects, so you just fill the textbox with userobj.getUsername();

Comment: {  
       username = data[0],  
       password = data[1],  
       address = data[2],  
       telephone = data[3],  
       dateOfBirth = data[4],  
 textBox1.Text = userobj.getUsername(); 

             

                                              };

something like that?

Comment: Check the 'csv' variable for its content